# FFmpeg 2 Pass Encoding

Tags: ffmpeg

I a trying to convert my high quality movie collection to save some disk space. And I learned that 2 Pass encoding will do the job better.
And this is the command line that I am using to encode videos with 2 pass.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=1920x1080" -vb 3.5M -pass 1 -an pass1.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=1920x1080" -vb 3.5M -pass 2 -c:a copy pass2.mp4
```

And this works fine. And I know that this command will give the output for the first pass also. That's fine. I will delete them. My doubt is, I read many forums that people use `-y` and `-passlogfile` commands in 2 pass encoding. What does `-y` and `-passlogfile` do?

Also is there any other setting can I add to improve the quality?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### tl;dr - Just use `-crf` with 1-pass unless you need a specific file size

- 1 pass is faster than 2 passes.
- 2-pass does not make a better quality or smaller file: it only lets you set the output file size (but not the quality), whereas `-crf` lets you choose the quality (but not the file size).

---

#### Questions

> I learned that 2 Pass encoding will do the job better.

Two-passes will to a better job *targeting a specific output file size*. Otherwise, just do a single pass with `-crf`.

> I know that this command will give the output for the first pass also. That's fine. I will delete them.

You could output to `/dev/null` (Linux & macOS) or `NUL` (Windows) instead and avoid making a temporary file:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=1920:1080" -b:v 3.5M -pass 1 -an -f mp4 /dev/null
ffmpeg -y -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=1920:1080" -b:v 3.5M -pass 2 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 - Two-Pass](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass) for more info and examples.

> What does `-y` and `-passlogfile` do?

- `-y` Overwrite output files without asking for confirmation. Makes sense for the first pass, otherwise it will ask you `File '/dev/null' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]`. Yes, you can "overwrite" `/dev/null`.
- `-passlogfile` Sets the two-pass log file name. You don't need to use this option unless you want to use a custom log file name instead of the default (`ffmpeg2pass-0.log`).

See the [`ffmpeg` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) for more info on these options.

> Also is there any other setting can I add to improve the quality?

- Use the slowest preset you have patience for. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).
- Increase the bitrate.
- Use a more efficient encoder, such as libx265. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265). Be aware that it is slow.
- Avoid upscaling. Experiment with different [scaling algorithms](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-scaler.html#Scaler-Options) to see what looks best to you: `"scale=1920:-2:flags=lanczos"`.
- **Buy another drive and don't re-encode.**

Comment: **1. "Use the slowest preset you have patience for"** - From the FFmpeg documentation, I thought those presets were only useful for crf encoding. So slower preset will also improve 2 pass. Right?

**2. "scale=1920:-2:flags=lanczos"** - I will definitely try different scaling algorithms. And what does -2 in the height do here? Is that same as -1?

Comment: @RvidD A slower preset will use a more efficient set of options which means that it will be slower to encode, but you will generally have a better quality per bit ratio. You can use it with any rate control method. The `-2` is like `-1`, but will make the value divisible by 2 which is needed for outputting H.264/H.265 with 4:2:0 chroma subsampling.

Comment: Can I run FFmpeg GPU assisted? My GPU is Geforce GTX 970m. Is that even a good idea to run FFmpeg with GPU assistance?

Comment: @RvidD Yes, see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro – particularly the part about NVENC. Some more info here: https://superuser.com/q/1296374/48078. This will improve encoding speed, but I don't know if NVENC for H.264 gives you better quality for the same bitrate, compared to libx264.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I encoded 2 pass video with slowpreset, placebo and without giving any preset. The results were different. slowpreset performed slightly worse than No preset. And placebo performed slightly worse than slowpreset. I also tested them with different videos and different bitrates. I took many screenshots and compared them and the results were same. This maybe because the second pass of the encoding has predefined parameters and may not need any preset setting that is required for crf encoding. I am using latest version of FFmpeg (Windows 64-bit, Static, nightly git)

Comment: @slhck I tried Nvidia NVENC. It is super fast (like 12-14x). But doesn't support 2-pass encoding and also quality is not as good as 2 pass encoded video for the same size.

Comment: I don't see how this can work. The command above does not create a stats file. If there is no stats file, there's no way for the 2nd pass to use the information from the 1st pass to make compression decisions. I know this all comes from some of the guides found on ffmpeg's website but there's definitely something missing because this essentially produces a single-pass CBR file.

Comment: @dsanchez It creates 2 stats files for me: `ffmpeg2pass-0.log` & `ffmpeg2pass-0.log.mbtree`. The command in the answer is only 1 of 2 commands needed for 2-pass encoding (see the question for command #2 or maybe I'll update the answer to include both).

Comment: @llogan The command line in this answer only creates 1 file for me, the log file. However, that file is empty. This command is missing the -x265-params option, which is what actually creates the proper stats files.

Comment: @dsanchez The question, command, and answer are referring to libx264, not libx265.

Comment: @llogan Ah, that's the difference. Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it, why 2-pass can't be used so that it uses more space in scenes with more moving parts? I often see results of jumpiness in end result where the bitrate wasn't enough for the scene.