# How do I convert 10-bit H.265 / HEVC videos to H.264 without quality loss?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding, x264, x265

My laptop can't handle 10bit H.265 / HEVC videos, so I'm looking to convert them to 10bit H.264. How do I do this using, say, ffmpeg, with the least quality loss? And how can I convert 10-bit H.265 to 8-bit H.265?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

## 10-bit/12-bit HEVC to 8-bit H.264

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -vf format=yuv420p -c:a copy output.mkv
```

- `-map 0` will include all streams (default stream selection only selects 1 stream per type). See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).
- Adjust the `-crf` value to provide the desired level of quality. Add the `-preset` option if you want to adjust encoding speed. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info on `-crf` and `-preset`.
- Uses the [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filter to choose the `yuv420p` pixel format to create 8-bit output.

## 10-bit/12-bit HEVC to 10-bit H.264

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

- `-map 0` will include all streams (default stream selection only selects 1 stream per type). See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).
- Adjust the `-crf` value to provide the desired level of quality. Add the `-preset` option if you want to adjust encoding speed. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info on `-crf` and `-preset`.
- No need for the format filter in this case.

## 10-bit/12-bit HEVC to 8-bit HEVC

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0 -c:v libx265 -crf 20 -vf format=yuv420p -c:a copy output.mkv
```

- `-map 0` will include all streams (default stream selection only selects 1 stream per type). See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).
- Adjust the `-crf` value to provide the desired level of quality. Add the `-preset` option if you want to adjust encoding speed. See [FFmpeg Wiki: HEVC / H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) for more info on `-crf` and `-preset`.
- Uses the [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filter to choose the `yuv420p` pixel format to create 8-bit output.

## 12-bit HEVC to 10-bit HEVC

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0 -c:v libx265 -crf 20 -vf format=yuv420p10le -c:a copy output.mkv
```

- `-map 0` will include all streams (default stream selection only selects 1 stream per type). See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).
- Adjust the `-crf` value to provide the desired level of quality. Add the `-preset` option if you want to adjust encoding speed. See [FFmpeg Wiki: HEVC / H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) for more info on `-crf` and `-preset`.
- Uses the [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filter to choose the `yuv420p10le` pixel format to create 10-bit output. Other 10-bit pixel formats supported by libx265 are `yuv422p10le` & `yuv444p10le`, but your player may not like these. See `ffmpeg -h encoder=libx265` for additional supported pixel formats.

Comment: What about 10bit x265 to 8bit x265?

Comment: @HappyFace Looks like I misread the question. I added that section.

Comment: Adding `-map 0` to the commands above will preserve subtitles and other additional streams.

Comment: PS4 only allow 8bit H264/AVC. But if use ffmpeg convert the 10bit H265/HEVC to H624, with preset, you will get the 10bit H264, which is not recognized on PS4 vedio player. This comment mark it useful for getting compability on PS4.

Comment: Consider this answer https://superuser.com/questions/1296374/best-settings-for-ffmpeg-with-nvenc/1549953#1549953

Answer (score 0):

[Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) can handle most anything.

The [release notes](https://handbrake.fr/news.php?article=39) mention 10-bit support.

The UI has all the options.  I suggest you start there and get familiar with it.
See [quick start guide](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/1.1.0/introduction/quick-start.html).

There is also a CLI that can be downloaded [here](https://handbrake.fr/downloads2.php).
And the [guide](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/1.1.0/cli/cli-guide.html) that has all the options laid out.

Comment: Can you add the complete command?

Comment: Added links to post, start with the UI - it has a queue so you can load up an entire folder at once if needed.