# GoPro Hero 8 HEVC convert to x264

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, gopro

I made a video with my GoPro Hero 8. When I play it with VLC player, the audio is OK but the screen is just black. I found that this may be caused by HEVC, so I downloaded FFMPEG from here: https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/

I tried to use the answer from this question: [How do I convert 10-bit H.265 videos to H.264 without quality loss?](https://superuser.com/questions/1380946/how-do-i-convert-10-bit-h-265-videos-to-h-264-without-quality-loss)

```
ffmpeg.exe -i ..\..\100GOPRO\GH010194.MP4 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy ..\..\100GOPRO\GH010194_x264.MP4
ffmpeg.exe -i ..\..\100GOPRO\GH010194.MP4 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -vf format=yuv420p -c:a copy ..\..\100GOPRO\GH010194_x264_8bit.MP4
ffmpeg.exe -i ..\..\100GOPRO\GH010194.MP4 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -vf format=yuv420p -c:a copy ..\..\100GOPRO\GH010194_x264_8bit.mkv
```

I did not get any error message, the computer was working for reasonable amount of time, and I got files of plausible size as output. However, when I play them, they are still black.

I tried ffprobe on this video, and received this output:

```
ffprobe version 2021-04-25-git-d98884be41-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 74.100 / 56. 74.100
  libavcodec     58.136.101 / 58.136.101
  libavformat    58. 78.100 / 58. 78.100
  libavdevice    58. 14.100 / 58. 14.100
  libavfilter     7.111.100 /  7.111.100
  libswscale      5. 10.100 /  5. 10.100
  libswresample   3. 10.100 /  3. 10.100
  libpostproc    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '..\..\100GOPRO\GH010194.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2021-04-27T17:07:48.000000Z
    firmware        : HD8.01.01.60.00
  Duration: 00:00:21.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 45431 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 45146 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-27T17:07:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AVC  
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 17:06:46:33
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-27T17:07:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC  
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      timecode        : 17:06:46:33
  Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-27T17:07:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro TCD  
      timecode        : 17:06:46:33
  Stream #0:3(eng): Data: bin_data (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 57 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-27T17:07:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET  
  Stream #0:4(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 14 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-27T17:07:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro SOS  
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
Unsupported codec with id 100359 for input stream 3
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 4
```

How can I convert this video to something I can view? Do I need Windows 10 for it?

**Update:**

I can play it on my Linux machine perfectly.
(But would like to do so on Win7, too.)

Comment: VLC has supported H.265/HEVC for about 5 years. What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Then idk, I haven't seen Win7 in years. Make sure you've got latest VLC that will still run on it… & plan your upgrade to a supported OS at the earliest opportunity. Win7 is not just dead but badly compromised.

Comment: You can see if enabling/disabling hardware accelerated decoding makes a difference: https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Hardware_acceleration/