# How do I convert 12-bit H.265 videos to 10-bit H.265 without quality loss?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, h.265

My laptop seems unable to handle 12bit HEVC videos efficiently. The video appears to stagger when I play it so I'm looking to convert them to 10bit H.265. How do I do this using, ffmpeg, with little or no quality loss?

**Edit**:  Okay so I managed to convert it from 12-bit to 10-bit but there is visible loss in quality on comparison. How do I maintain quality while converting to 10-bit output?

This is the command I used `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx265 -vf format=yuv420p10le -c:a copy output.mkv`
Should I try a specific -crf/cbr?

The enable/disable hardware acceleration option in media player didn't do well to play the 12-bit video.

**Solved**: Okay so the quality issue has been solved. I tried three commands and the all worked equally good.

The first `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx265 -crf 16 -vf format=yuv420p10le -c:a copy output.mkv` This resulted in almost identical visual quality and the same size as the original video.

The second (by @harrymc) `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -x265-params profile=main10 out.mkv` This one also resulted in equally good visual quality as the above but somehow, it reduced my file size to nearly half so it seems the best command of all three to me.

The third (by @Anmol Mishra), `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -c:v libx265 -crf 23 -preset slow -tune grain out.mkv` This too had no loss in visual quality that's apparent to naked eye and also reduced file size by a quarter.

Thank you everyone for help.

Comment: Did you try enabling/disabling hardware accelerated decoding?

Comment: @llogan How to enable/disable hardware accelerated decoding? I saw your [answer on a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/1381151/1065601) where you a gave command to convert 10-bit H.265 to 8-bit H.265.  Can I change "vf- format=yuv420p" to something to get a 10-bit output?

Comment: @harrymc Your command works to convert the video into x264 output but I am looking for x265 10-bit output.

Comment: I deleted the previous erroneous comment. Try `pix_fmt` for specifying 10-bit, which requires rendering (not copy) like: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -x265-params profile=main10 out.mkv`.

Comment: @Sanchit I was referring to your player. If you can improve playing then you don't need to re-encode. (I'm not too familiar with hardware accelerated decoding, so I'm unsure if there are any that can actually decode 12-bit HEVC, and I didn't research it, so it might be a moot point.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a visual lossless equivalent crf and tune. Read the x265 page here - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265 and here - https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=172458

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -c:v libx265 -crf 23 -preset slow -tune grain film out.mkv`

x264 will get blocky while x265 will blur. To offset some of the blur, the -tune grain will bring in smaller detail. Do not try to modify other parameters unless you truly understand HEVC.

Depending on the space you have, you can test crf values from 20-23, I could not find much of a difference.