# Why using b-frames does not reduce the size of my video (using ffmpeg and nvenc)?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have this command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec h264_nvenc -rc vbr_hq -cq 19 -rc-lookahead:v 32 -preset slow -profile:v main -c:a copy output.mp4
```

For my one-minute test video, it produces a file about 82.5 MB big in about 5 seconds.

I tried adding option to use B-frames: `-bf:v 3`, but it only increases the encoding time byt about 1.5 seconds, but the file size does not change. B-frames are used as confirmed by `ffprobe -show_frames output.mp4 | grep "pict_type"`. Am I missing something? I thought B-frames should decrease the file size. My card is GeForce GTX 1650 Max-Q and it should suppport it. I am aiming for visual losslessness with good encoding speeds so I am using GPU instead of CPU. A file size is not such a big concern, but the smaller, the better. I am burning in subtitles.

Why is not using B-frames reducing the size of the video? Is it somehow increasing its perceptual quality (I hope that is not even possible with my settings)?

A couple of bonus questions:

1. Do I need `-rc-lookahead:v 32`? I see it used a lot (for example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1296374/best-settings-for-ffmpeg-with-nvenc)) but the default should be 40, so I am not sure about this one.
2. Is `-cq 19` really the value I should use if I am aiming for perceptual losslessnes? It comes from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1236275/how-can-i-use-crf-encoding-with-nvenc-in-ffmpeg/1236387) but I could not really find any other sources for this value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of B-frames in a hardware-based encoder implementation, specifically NVENC (be it for both H.264 and HEVC wrappers) will not directly influence the output size of an encoded file, all other factors remaining constant.

B-frames typically increase the decoder resources required to process the output, which is why the Baseline profiles have it disabled.

If you want explicit control over output size(s), then you must set the target bitrate (`-b:v`), maximum bitrate (`-maxrate:v`) and buffer size (`-bufsize:v`) to appropriate values, as per your needs. NVENC's defaults for this are insane, at about ~256 kb/s. You must therefore either set these values above by hand OR explicitly unset it altogether by passing `-b:v 0`.

On to the question of rate control look-ahead (private option `-rc-lookahead:v`), this is mostly useful when combined with multiple B-frames (`-bf:v n` where `n > 2` ). In this case, the encoder will dynamically select the number of B-Frames between 0 and the number of B-Frames you specify.

In practice, B-frames are great because they increase image quality, but they consume a lot of bit-rate which negatively impacts the perceptual quality (PQ) of high motion content. This is a factor to consider in some applications, such as live streaming.

Note that any form of weighted prediction cannot be combined with the use of B-frames in NVENC, so weigh your encoding requirements carefully before toggling either option.

For your workload, here are two approaches you can consider (with the caveats on bit rate control as documented above):

**1. Constant quality mode in VBR rate control:**
For `-cq`, note that this toggles on constant quality encoding mode when rate control (toggled via `-rc:v` in NVENC) is set to VBR (Variable bitrate) and its' variants. The scale it uses is logarithmic, with `1` being the highest possible quality mode and `51` being the lowest quality mode. The default setting of `0` implies automatic.

**2. Constant quantization parameter rate control method:**

This mode requires that rate control mode be explicitly set to `constqp`, via the private codec option `rc:v constqp` and the argument `-qp:v` be present, with valid values starting from `0` to `51`. This can be further capped via the minimum and maximum allowable quantization values set via `-qmin:v {int}` and `-qmax:v {int}` respectively.

In my testing, I've been able to achieve the best results with method (2) above, ie setting a constant quantizer in effect and selecting the rate control method to `constqp`, as shown in the two examples below:

(a). Using a quantizer value of 0:

```sh
ffmpeg -y -i dnce.mkv -vf 'hwupload_cuda=0,yadif_cuda=0:-1:0,scale_cuda=w=1920:h=1080' -c:v h264_nvenc -rc:v constqp -tune:v hq -preset:v p7 -qp:v 0 -b:v 0 -c:a copy nv-test-7.ts
```

(b). Using a quantizer value of 19:

```sh
ffmpeg -y -i dnce.mkv -vf 'hwupload_cuda=0,yadif_cuda=0:-1:0,scale_cuda=w=1920:h=1080' -c:v h264_nvenc -rc:v constqp -tune:v hq -preset:v p7 -qp:v 19 -b:v 0 -c:a copy nv-test-8.ts
```

in these cases, the encode with a QP of 0 produced an output of 8.8 GB, whereas the latter, at a QP of 19, produced an output file of 1.3GB.
The output had to be deinterlaced in both cases.

The most confusing result I got was with the constant quality mode, as documented in (1) above:

(a). Using a target quality level of 0 in VBR mode:

```sh
ffmpeg -y -i dnce.mkv -vf 'hwupload_cuda=0,yadif_cuda=0:-1:0,scale_cuda=w=1920:h=1080' -c:v h264_nvenc -rc:v vbr -tune:v hq -preset:v p7 -cq:v 0 -b:v 0 -c:a copy nv-test-3.ts
```

(b). Using a target quality level of 19 in VBR mode:

```sh
ffmpeg -y -i dnce.mkv -vf 'hwupload_cuda=0,yadif_cuda=0:-1:0,scale_cuda=w=1920:h=1080' -c:v h264_nvenc -rc:v vbr -tune:v hq -preset:v p7 -cq:v 19 -b:v 0 -c:a copy nv-test-4.ts
```

in this case, the output sizes for a CQ setting of 0 and 19 were 797 and 790MB respectively.

Your mileage may differ, depending on your input files and the underlying muxer(s) in use, as each muxer in FFmpeg has differing overheads, etc.

Be careful not to mix and match parameters,as my previous answer had, which resulted in skewed observations that did not hold up under further scrutiny.

Comment: Thank you. As to the NVENC default - I do not set `-b:v` and with the line as per my question, I get an average bitrate around 6MBt/s (55 minute video is 5,9 GB). What do you mean by "weighted predictions" - the settings regarding the bitrate? As per `-cq` what is the highest value that achieves perceptual equality between source and target? I could not really tell the difference between 19 and 24, but I do not trust my eyes so I would like to know if there is some conventional value.

Comment: @sup , for your workload, just set `-b:v 0`. Weighted prediction calculates a multiplicative weighting factor and an additive offset to the motion compensated prediction, providing significant quality gain for contents having illumination changes at the cost of eliminating B-frames and slight encoder throughput degradation. For `-cq`, set it to 19. That should give you visually identical perceptual quality to the source material.

Comment: Thank you, that answers all my questions!

Comment: Ha, just an observation - adding `-b:v 0` cut a size of one ideo I just encoded 3.5times!

Comment: That's how your selected rate control mode (`-rc:v vbr_hq`) should work, with explicitly unsetting the target bitrate via `-b:v 0`. Do reach out for any further clarifications and queries on NVENC.